# Spyder keeps crashing in virtual python environment in OSX

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder

I'm running an OSX Mountain Lion installation of Spyder (version ['spyder-2.2.0beta2.zip'](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list)) inside a virtual environment setup using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and the [Enthought](http://www.enthought.com/products/edudownload.php) academic build of Python.  The setup loads up okay, but crashes whenever I am inside the 'save as' dialogue box, specifically as soon as I click on the 'Where:' dropdown box to select a folder.  The terminal used to open Spyder then reports `Segmentation fault: 11`.  Any ideas whats causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Spyder dev here) This is not our fault nor Enthought's one, but [PySide's](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide): the Python Qt bindings distributed by Enthought. Unfortunately they are not very stable (causing crashes like the one you described) and currently unmaintained, so we can't do anything about it.

Our recommended installation method on Mac is using our [DMG](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/detail?name=spyder-2.2.0beta2_Lion.dmg&can=2&q=) (which uses PyQt4, a more stable set of bindings) and then switch your interpreter to the EPD's one. Or use MacPorts, if you feel brave enough :-)

Comment: Ah that helps, thanks Carlos. As for Macports, no fear I've just spent 2 painful days figuring out how to remove it and install a functional alternative! Guess I'll just try and work round the glitches till someone patches PySide properly.

Comment: Or you could use Homebrew to install PyQt4. IMHO it's more lightweight and easy to use than MacPorts. About PySide: We have a PySide expert and he told us about the sad abandonment of the project by Nokia.

Comment: The DMG link you provided is for Lion. Are you sure it works on Mountain Lion?

Comment: I don't have access to Mountain Lion to test it but I've heard from several people that it runs just fine.